# Starting sidekiq with capistrano

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, sidekiq

I want to start sidekiq with capistrano. Below is code for that

```
namespace :sidekiq do
  task :start do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -e production -L log/sidekiq.log &"
    p capture("ps aux | grep sidekiq | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n 1p").strip!    
  end
end
```

It executes successfully but still sidekiq is not started on server.

output:

```
$ cap sidekiq:start
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2014-06-03 15:03:01 executing `sidekiq:start'
  * executing "cd /home/project/current && bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -e production -L log/sidekiq.log &"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 1229ms
  * executing "ps aux | grep sidekiq | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n 1p"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 1229ms
"19291"
```

Comment: So how are you killing the previous sidekiq process?

Comment: sidekiq_process_id = capture("ps aux | grep sidekiq | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n 1p").strip!;
run "kill -15 #{sidekiq_process_id}"
And it kills successfully :)

Comment: Why not use existing gem? https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq

Comment: I don't want a gem for single line of code.

Comment: @sagarjunnarkar - It would make your life easier. ANyway, anything interesting in `log/sidekiq.log`. Last time I had similar issue it seemed to start correctly and then it simply crashed.

Comment: Never mind, I think I see the issue.

Comment: Yes it is. It tells you when actually job is processed. Also, if redis is down, it comes in sidekiq log. So it is important.

Comment: @sagarjunnarkar - I know it is important I was asking whether there are any obvious errors in there, not why you need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
  cd /home/project/current && bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -e production -L log/sidekiq.log &
```

When you add `&` at the end command is being executed in a separate process, but this process is still a child of a current process and is terminated when current process stops. Instead you need to run sidekiq as a deamon.

```
bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -e production -L log/sidekiq.log -d
```

Note the extra `-d` option

Comment: @sagarjunnarkar - What is your sidekiq version?

Comment: Sidekiq version is 2.6.0

Comment: @sagarjunnarkar - `-d` option has been added in 2.7.0. You can try running `sidekiq help` and check whether there is any equivalent (like --deamon)

Comment: Thanks its working. Just last question. Is it ok if I just change sidekiq version in Gemfile or do I have to make lots of changes in code?

Comment: @sagarjunnarkar - TO use 2.7 instead? I am not entirely sure what else have change between those two versions, but I wouldn't say much. Give it a go for a couple of weeks and search for issues with workers but it should go pretty smoothly.

Answer (score 10):

Without making use of any gem, here is my solution working perfectly with Capistrano 3.4.0

```
namespace :sidekiq do

  task :restart do
    invoke 'sidekiq:stop'
    invoke 'sidekiq:start'
  end

  before 'deploy:finished', 'sidekiq:restart'

  task :stop do
    on roles(:app) do
      within current_path do
        pid = p capture "ps aux | grep sidekiq | awk '{print $2}' | sed -n 1p"
        execute("kill -9 #{pid}")
      end
    end
  end

  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      within current_path do
        execute :bundle, "exec sidekiq -e #{fetch(:stage)} -C config/sidekiq.yml -d"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wont this create some issues when sidekiq is not already running?

Comment: Its safer to do `pgrep sidekiq` instead of `grep sidekiq | awk '{print $2}'`. This makes sure you wont take grep command pid instead of sidekiq. Also in case there are multiple sidekiq processes, you better kill all processes that you find

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somehow trying to `start`/`restart`/`stop` environment with `capistrano`:

```
bundle exec cap production sidekiq:start
bundle exec cap production sidekiq:stop
bundle exec cap production sidekiq:restart
#staging
bundle exec cap staging sidekiq:start
bundle exec cap staging sidekiq:stop
bundle exec cap staging sidekiq:restart
#same with other dependencies
bundle exec cap production puma:restart
bundle exec cap staging puma:stop
```

*Brief explanation*

(in case you are hitting a repo online, like github remember to run your ssh agent to connect via ssh in the repo and pull latest version of the code/branch)

- setup your own github ssh key locally
- run ssh agent with the key `eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
- check agent with `ssh -T git@github.com`

After that i always use this to deploy

- run capistrano targeting env `bundle exec cap staging deploy`

And these are really handy when you are already in prod and had issues but specially for staging, you could do individual exec depending on your `Capfile` (for instance most of the time i use `puma` as `rack middleware` server and `sidekiq` for `scheculed-jobs`)

*Capfile*

```
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require "capistrano/yarn"
require "capistrano/puma"
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma  # Default puma tasks
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
require 'slackistrano/capistrano'
require_relative 'lib/capistrano/slack_deployment_message'
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

So in the end for executing `start`|`stop`|`restart` on these features enabled/installed/configured by `capistrano`

I could always restart puma with capistrano in production:

- `bundle exec cap production sidekiq:restart`
- `bundle exec cap production puma:restart`

As well as in staging:

- `bundle exec cap staging sidekiq:restart`
- `bundle exec cap staging puma:restart`

Hope this helps!
:D